# Active MQ, Only one of many MessageListeners stuck while reading still causes queue to grow

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a weird behavior on an ActiveMQ queue i can't understand. Not super-good at ActiveMQ so i'm hoping that someone can help out.

I have a queue, configured in tomcat. I have a MessageListener configured through Spring with 3 instances.
They basically do an HTTP request, process the answer and put the answer on another queue.

Yesterday, i had connectivity issues, so the (SOAP) requests timed out. When that happens, I throw a custom exception, catch it in "onMessage" and send an error message on the response queue.
I can then see that the listener took another message off the queue, and then hung. No exception or anything. Why this happened i'm not sure of, i'm investigating that.

**But here's the strange thing:**

This happened to 2 of my three MessageListeners. They stopped, but my third one still reads from the queue. HOWEVER, the queue is growing and the queuesize was more than 500 messages before i restarted the server.

The two listeners that were hung each had a "dispatchedqueuesize" of about half of that each.

So, to me it seems that the messages that were put on the queue become "reserved" for each of the listeners, even if they don't actively read from the queue. I can see that the "active" listener still process messages, so why doesn't it process every message?? I want the listeners to just read messages in the order they come in. If only one "is left" it should still read every message put on the queue. Why isn't it doing that??

Pointers much appreciated.

EDIT: Spring config for receiving end below.

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="refConnectionFactory" brokerURL="${jms.broker.url}" clientID="theclient"/>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="refConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- listener container definition using the jms namespace, concurrency is the max number of concurrent listeners that can be started -->
<jms:listener-container concurrency="3">
    <jms:listener id="locationListener" destination="location.out" ref="locationQueryListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the thread is hung in your code somewhere; use jstack to get a thread dump to see what the container threads are doing.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't explain why the queue keeps growing. The remaning listener continues to read, but only seems to read about every third message, it should read every one. Got a tip somewhere else that it might be because of the prefetch setting. Gonna look at that.